# Canvas draw text () not show text on secreen

Tags: java, android, fonts

i am trying to drawtext on screen.
but nothing show on the secreen.help me plz.
my code is here .

Main.java class

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity 

 {


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int w = 30, h = 30;

    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); 
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);


    Paint paint = new Paint();
 Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"RECOGNITION.ttf");
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    paint.setTypeface(face) ;
    paint.setTextSize(20); 
    canvas.drawText("Some Text", 30, 30, paint); 

  }
```

but nothing show on the screen.

my xml is here..
mystyle.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is your canvas color?

Comment: don't know ,this is my all code.

Comment: can u comment 
  Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); 
and try it..

Comment: no change happend,show blank screen..:(

Answer (score 0):

Try this
-Main.java--

```
public class MAIN extends Activity {
    CustomDrawableView mCustomDrawableView; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this);        
        setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);

    }
}
```

--CustomDrawableView.java--

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
//private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
int x=0;
int y=0;

public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 5, mPaint);
}
```

}

Comment: check this https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/707993-how-to-draw-2d-object-in-android-with-a-canvas